# How to close sql connection when using mysql2/promise?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I have such nodejs code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123123",
    database: "mydatabase"
})
.then((connection) => connection.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable"))
.then(([rows, fields]) => {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

When I execute it, application prints array of database rows and is still running after that. Seems it happens because connection isn't released. How to release it after `console.log`?

I've tried this way:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123123",
    database: "mydatabase"
})
.then((connection) => {
    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
    .then(([rows, fields]) => {
        console.log(rows);
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

but result is `TypeError: this.connection.release is not a function`.

Sorry for my English.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `release` is the correct function name. The [reference documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#terminating-connections) implies it's `end` or `destroy`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `mysql2` mostly keeps API compatibility with `mysql`, you should be able to close the connection with `connection.end()`.

Comment: I'm using [node mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and getting "Calling conn.end() to release a pooled connection is deprecated. In next version calling conn.end() will be restored to default conn.end() behavior. Use conn.release() instead" so from now on conn.release() seems to be the way to go